# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException with mysql DataSource

Tags: java, mysql, datasource, jndi

Trying to connect to a MySQL database

```
MysqlDataSource mysqlDs = new MysqlDataSource();
Properties prop = new Properties();
String mysqlDataSourceDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource";  
Properties properties = new Properties();  
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, mysqlDataSourceDriver); 
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL , "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(prop);
ctx.bind("jdbc/wczasy", mysqlDs);
```

And the stacktrace:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or     system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:      java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:419)
at src.wczasy.database.Connector.connect(Connector.java:53)
at src.wczasy.Wczasy.main(Wczasy.java:10)
```

Caused by line: ctx.bind("jdbc/wczasy", mysqlDs); 
I am stuck, can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `MysqlDataSource` is not implementing `javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory` interface.

If you are not in a container you can use rmi registry. Something like:

```
try{
  startRegistry();
  InitialContext context = createContext();
  MysqlDataSource mysqlDs = new MysqlDataSource();
  context.rebind("jdbc/wczasy", mysqlDs);
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Error while binding: " + e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace();
}


private static void startRegistry() throws RemoteException {
  LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
  System.out.println("RMI registry ready.");
}

private static InitialContext createContext() throws NamingException {
  Properties env = new Properties();
  env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");
  env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "rmi://localhost:1099");
  InitialContext context = new InitialContext(env);
  return context;
}
```

Comment: Explanation and a working example is what we all seek for. Thank you very much!